# Translating a UIView and setting the label text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm starting to learn iOS gesture recognizers, going through this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/ios-gesture-recognizers/. Have a problem translating a view with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` while setting the `UILabels`' text to the gesture's velocity.

I have been successfully translating a view with a pan gesture like this (with the help of IB):

PanViewController.h

```
@interface PanViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *horizontalVelocityLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *verticalVelocityLabel;

@end
```

PanViewController.m

```
@interface PanViewController ()

- (void)moveViewWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer;

@end

@implementation PanViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveViewWithGestureRecognizer:)];
    [self.testView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)moveViewWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

    self.testView.center = touchLocation;
}
```

But when I add the following lines to this method, the view stops translating, but the UILabels get updated with the velocity:

```
CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:self.view];

self.horizontalVelocityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal Velocity: %.2f points/sec", velocity.x];
self.verticalVelocityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertical Velocity: %.2f points/sec", velocity.y];
```

I'd like to understand what i'm doing wrong. How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the whole recognizer method as is where it's not working?

Comment: Here's the whole code of pan view controller - (https://github.com/NatalyT/GesturesDemo/blob/master/GesturesDemo/PanViewController.m). The recognizer method is `moveViewWithGestureRecognizer:`. I try to move the object to the bottom of the screen (or anywhere), but the object doesn't move. When I stop moving the mouse cursor, the object simply skip to the point where cursor is. Then when I go to move it again, it first resets itself to the center before it moves. This issue appears after adding the last 3 lines of the recognizer method.

Comment: I tested your code (manually adding view and labels) and everything worked.  The problem isn't in your recognizer code.  Is auto-layout turned on?

Comment: @Dave, yes, auto-layout was turned on. Turning the auto-layout off in Main.storyboard solved the problem.

Comment: Great! Now just write an answer to your question detailing the steps to solve your problem so others will benefit.  You can't mark a comment as the correct answer, but you can upvote it.